# Как выйти из приложения при клике Назад

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Видите ли, тут у меня `onBackPressed` и используется для перехода назад во фрагментах. И мне нужно когда закончатся фрагменты показывал сообщение о выходе. Но у меня ничего не делает то есть даже не выходит из приложения.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: `finish();` пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не вызываете изначальную реализацию метода `onBackPressed()`. Если я правильно прочёл ваши мысли, то вам надо проверять остались ли фрагменты во FragmentManager и если только один остался, то вызвать `super.onBackPressed()`

Comment: Спасибо, Не заметил, удалилось оказ!